# Selenium with Webdrivermanager : AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have the following code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

And get the following error :

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\untitled2.py:11 in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\TFE\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py:45 in __init__
    super().__init__(

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\TFE\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py:51 in __init__
    self.service.path = DriverFinder.get_path(self.service, options)

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\TFE\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py:40 in get_path
    msg = f"Unable to obtain driver for {options.capabilities['browserName']} using Selenium Manager."

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'
```

Does anyone know where it could be from?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I was getting same error as yours. I tried following code and it works.

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

# Set the executable path for the Chrome WebDriver
chrome_options.add_argument("webdriver.chrome.driver=[your chrome driver path sould be here]")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://www.google.ca")
print(driver.title)
driver.close()
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

My selenium has no ChromeDriverManager function or class, it can be the version problem.

it is a string returned by ChromeDriverManager().install()

```
class WebDriver(ChromiumDriver):
    """Controls the ChromeDriver and allows you to drive the browser."""
    def __init__(
        self,
        options: Options = None,
        service: Service = None,
        keep_alive: bool = True,
    ) -> None:
        self.service = service if service else Service()
        self.options = options if options else Options()
        self.keep_alive = keep_alive

        self.service.path = DriverFinder.get_path(self.service, self.options)
```